# Compile a document without traditional pages

Tags: pdftex, page-breaking

I want to compile a document so that each "page" will be one chapter (or section). These "pages" wouldn't be of any standard, they wouldn't even be the same sizes. I want to influence the width of the paper, but to let the length of the paper go on as long as it needs for the whole chapter (or section).

I need it so I can compile the document for reading on mobile phone. The page-breaks are distracting and meaningless to me when read digitally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the standalone class along with minipages:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,multi=minipage]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\lipsum
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{15cm}
\lipsum
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```